# HSBC CPI problem from ASP

Tags: com, asp-classic, windows-server-2003

We have been using the HSBC payment component for a while, running on a windows 2003 r2 sp1 box,  however we now have to move it to a 2003 r2 sp2 box (both 23 bit)

We have registered the CcCpiTools.dll and set permissions on the Dll’s to Everyone and added it to the system32 folder (with its CcCpiTools.dll), but for some reason get the Error 
“ActiveX component can't create object: 'CcCpiCOM.OrderHash'”

Would anyone know why we are getting this, are there any new security features in 2003 sp2 that’s blocking the dll being executed from ASP? The website is set to allow execute permission

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You might have possibly missed to install a dependent library - check the original locations running application with DependencyViewer. I remember there was a separate KB install for a DLL that hosted unmanaged encryption and hashing algorithms - search MSDN for CAPICOM.DLL.

Comment: Thanks for that, though didn't fix the problem, thanks though